# Splitting mesh when duplicating and sliding edges/vertices

Tags: modeling

Is there a way to duplicate a selected face/edges/vertices etc on a mesh - slide it down an axis on the original face and have it split/intersect/subdivide the face it is sitting on after it has been duplicated?

However I try this I end up with a second face sitting on top of the original face, rather than it splitting/intersecting the area I have moved it to.

Apologies if this is obvious but it seems like it should be a fairly standard operation and I cannot work out the way to do it.

As a very basic example I want to duplicate the face of this square

[image]

And slide it down to this position, intersecting mesh where it lands. Rather than sitting on top as a separate face.

[image]